# Issues cloning EC2 instance with new keypair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I'm having an issue assigning a new keypair with a cloned EC2 instance.  I was under the impression that I could

1. make an AMI out of an instance
2. launch new instance from AMI
3. Assign a different keypair
4. login with the new keypair

From my testing, the original keypair was there and my new one couldn't get in.  What I tried was

1. adding the new keypair to the original instance
2. create new AMI
3. launch instance from AMI
4. login with new keypair.

The way the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file was written was the same as the original instance.  When launching from an AMI, shouldn't the new keys overwrite the authorized_keys?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The new instance at startup should overwrite the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of your default user.  The default user being the one in your `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` file.  For example:

```
user: ubuntu
disable_root: 1
preserve_hostname: False
# datasource_list: ["NoCloud", "ConfigDrive", "OVF", "MAAS", "Ec2", "CloudStack"]

cloud_init_modules:
 - bootcmd
 - resizefs
 - set_hostname
 - update_hostname
 - update_etc_hosts
 - ca-certs
 - rsyslog
- ssh
...
```

Comment: Beware if you've updated cloud-init before making the new AMI. The latest version of cloud-init may replace your old cloud.cfg with a new one which changes the default user from ec2-user to "cloud-user". You can set it back to "ec2-user" by setting system_info:default_user:name in the new cloud.cfg.